# Сохранение массива объектов в localStorage js

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть массив объектов 
var users = [{name: ‘Alex’, age: 20},
{name: ‘Oleg’, age: 30}];

Как сохранить users в localStorage?

Answer (score 6):

```
localStorage.setItem('storedUsers', JSON.stringify(users));
...
var users = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('storedUsers'))
  users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedUsers'));
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!